# Spark json schema validation

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, validation, schema

I am using python library Draft7Validator (https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validate/) to test json schema for each file. Unfortunately it is slow, is there a library in scala/java that I could use in Spark to validate json schema for each file.

Comment: check this - https://github.com/circe/circe-json-schema

Answer (score 1):

You can use [everit](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema/) for json validation. You can find a sample [here](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-json-schema-in-java)
I think @Srinivas also provided a good option [circe-json-schema](https://github.com/circe/circe-json-schema), but everit (which is a base library for circe-json-schema) supports different Drafts also, so it would depend on your validation requirements and the Draft to use

Comment: We are using Draft7 so everit should be fine. How would you advice architecting solution so that each file must be validated and if incorrect moved to different directory. I want to implement bulk validation process.

Comment: You can traverse all json file names under the folder structure you have and after loading the `schema-validarion.json` used by everit you can run a `foreach` over the list (using a stream in Java or just the list in Scala) checking whether the file passes the validation and move the file to the "validation-passed" or to "validation-failed" folders. That way you wouldn't have conflicts with the files as they would be in different locations (even different than source) and later you can do whatever you want with the passed or failed files. You can even run in parallel with `.parallelStream`

Comment: Or if you are using Scala, just add `.par` to parallelize the execution

Comment: Thanks for that, I will test it.

Comment: everit is failing to recognize type [struct]
org.everit.json.schema.SchemaException: #: unknown type: [struct]

Comment: Can you please add the schema here so that we can check? As the exception says on the documentation http://erosb.github.io/everit-json-schema/javadoc/1.9.2/org/everit/json/schema/SchemaException.html, this must be because of the schema is not correct (or not supported type). Where are you using that struct type? Thank you

Comment: I learned that json does not support structs, I renamed types to array, as I am testing everit I got exception 

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(json);
        JSONObject jsonSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(<path>));

        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        JSONObject jsonSubject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(<path>));


        Schema schemaValidator = SchemaLoader.load((jsonSchema));
        schemaValidator.validate(jsonSubject);'

org.everit.json.schema.ValidationException: #: expected type: JSONArray, found: JSONObject

Comment: Can you add the json where you check that json array?. I think that's failing because the format you are using is not correct, sorry. I need to see the definition of the field and the value that is set on that one. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right problem. The issue is with our schema, it is too complex for this library. I tried with something basic and it worked. I will look for behaviour in different library.